# Android emulator doesn't show index.html

Tags: android, angularjs, android-studio, android-emulator, ionic-framework

I am learning ionic framework by looking at the docs and installed Android Studio with SDK manager.

I am creating a sample ToDo project which is described in ionic website:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html

When I test the app using `ionic serve`, it displays the index.html in browser(like shown here- http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html), but I want it to be rendered in my emulator.

I want to see how the ionic list and other ionic icons look in the emulator. 
But the android emulator always shows this view, not sure how can I get the index.html view: 
[image]

I tried following commands, but none helped me:

```
ionic emulate android
ionic run android
```

Any help or idea is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I didn't mention this in my earlier post but I already added and build  android in my project and it was successful.

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
ionic emulate android
```

Comment: [this guide here](http://gonehybrid.com/build-your-first-mobile-app-with-the-ionic-framework-part-4/) seems prety descriptive of what steps you have to follow

Comment: in general you shoud first add the android platform with `$ ionic platform android` then build the .apk with `$ ionic build android` and finally run the emulator `$ ionic emulate android`

Comment: @Akis- please check my EDIT